# Format a Excel Sheet as a Table using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, epplus

I have a .NET Core application, and I'm new to using the EPPlus library with C#.

I have a data table filled with data which I'm currently inserting into an Excel sheet using EPPlus.

I was wondering if there is a way to format the sheet as a table after you added the data to the sheet and not before?

(Like when you are using the "Format as table" function in Excel)

Sample of my code which only fills the Excel sheet:

```
var excelWorkSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["WorkSheet1"];

using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Load(dr);
}

excelWorkSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

excel.SaveAs(df);
```

Please keep in mind the `df` variable above is of type file directory, and that the data in the data-table will be different for each user so the size will never be the same for two users.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes this can be done with EPPlus. You can use `Dimension` if you do not have fixed rows/columns.

```
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;


ExcelWorksheet ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

//create a range for the table
ExcelRange range = ws.Cells[1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Row, ws.Dimension.End.Column];

//add a table to the range
ExcelTable tab = ws.Tables.Add(range, "Table1");

//format the table
tab.TableStyle = TableStyles.Medium2;
```

Comment: For me currently, this creates some kind of problem in the workbook, when Excel opens it it says it needs to repair it, if I confirm, it does open, but says it repaired something. When I `diff` the packages (by renaming xlsx to zip and extracting) the differences are minor... not sure what's wrong.